# How to emulate lower resolution digitized data (higher step-size)

Tags: analog-to-digital, digital, resolution

I am a statistician by training, and I am very new to signal processing, but I would appreciate some help and patience!

Suppose I have a digitized signal measured at a given frequency, range, resolution (in bits), and step size ($\text{range}/ 2^\text{resolution}$).

I want to compute a summary of the signal (the summaries vary, but they usually include some kind of average of a non-linear transformation of the signal value). Then I want to determine what my summary would be if I had collected the data with a one-bit lower resolution (doubling the step size).

I would think that there is likely not a "correct" way of doing this, but what might be a reasonable method of emulating data collected with a doubled step size? Could I smooth the signal, and then round the smoothed values to the new steps?